# Grafana is not working on kubernetes cluster while using k8s Service

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I am trying to setup a very simple monitoring cluster for my k8s cluster. I have successfully created prometheus pod and is running fine.
When I tried to create grafana pod the same way, its not accessible through the node port.

My Grafana deploy file is-

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grafana-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: grafana
          image: grafana/grafana:5.1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

And Service File is --

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-service
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: grafana-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Note- When I am creating a simple docker container on the same host using same image, its working fine.

Comment: what error are you getting. grafana pod takes a while to be ready. wait upto 5 minutes then retry to connect.

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl get svc grafana-service -n monitoring' ? What port is it listening on?

Comment: Hello vivek, welcome to SO. It is considered very poor form to post code snippets as images, especially when the snippets in question are only 6-7 lines long. That prevents others from being able to search for parts of your question that might help their situation. Please update your question to include the YAML. The editor has support for code fragments and will help you format them nicely. Good luck!

Comment: @EmruzHossain There is no specific error. Service and deployment both are successful. Pod is also running. But when I am trying to access it from browser, web page is not available.
output of 'kubectl get svc -n monitoring' is --

grafana-service   NodePort   10.100.34.85   <none>        3000:30658/TCP   25h

Comment: @antweiss
output of kubectl get svc -n monitoring is  ` grafana-service   NodePort   10.100.34.85   <none>        3000:30658/TCP   25h
 `

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel
Thank you for the suggestion. Made the necessary changes.

Comment: @vivek what url are you using to access  grafana? you should use `http://<node ip>:30658`.

Comment: @EmruzHossain yes, I am using same URL.

Comment: @vivek what is in  Grafana's logs? `kubectl logs -n monitoring -l app=grafana-server`

Comment: ` t=2018-11-28T06:58:50+0000 lvl=info msg="Initializing CleanUpService" logger=cleanup
t=2018-11-28T07:01:17+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302 remote_addr=10.244.0.0 time_ms=0 size=29 referer=`

**Grafana logs seems noral. Also when I checked with elinks using cluster IP, grafana docs page is available.**

Answer (score 0):

I have come to know that my servers provider had not enabled these ports (like grafana-3000, kibana-5601). Never thought of this since i am using these servers from quite a long time and never faced such blocker. They implemented these rules recently.
Well, after some port approvals, I tried the same config again and it worked like a charm.